# Python parallell for-loop breaks after x iterations

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize a for loop. In each iteration I load data into a dataframe, do some operations and make a plot that I save as a pdf. The code is below.

This works, but it breaks at some point. Sometimes after 80 iterations, sometimes after 120. I get also different error messages (I don't have them anymore, but could try to generate them if needed).

Any idea why this is happening? Can you see something in the code that is wrong?

```
def operation(ID):
    load data into a dataframe

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
    
    x = dframe.x
    y = dframe.y
    plt.hist2d(x, y)

    plt.savefig(os.path.join('/my_folder/', f'hist2d_{ID}.pdf'), bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close(fig)



import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

N_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

pool = ThreadPool(N_cores - 2)  # Number of threads

pool.map(operation, list_of_IDs)
```

Comment: This is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- and what little you show can't even be compiled, such as the first line of function `operation`, namely `load data into a dataframe`, which is not valid Python.

Comment: And what do you mean by it fails after the *80th iteration*? Do you mean it fails after processing the 80th item of `list_of_IDs[:]`? And why are you passing  `list_of_IDs[:]` to map instead of  `list_of_IDs`?

Comment: Yes, it fails sometimes after the 80th item, sometimes after the 120th, etc. I passed list_of_IDs[:] because, for testing, I used to pass to the function list_of_IDs[:10]

Comment: When you pass `list_of_IDs[:]`, you are unnecessarily making a copy of `list_of_IDs`.

Comment: maybe "load data into a dataframe" raises some error. Put it in a try/except block

Answer (score 0):

The code worked changing from multithreading to multiprocessing. Basically, I changed:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(N_cores - 2)
```

for this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(N_cores - 2)
```